# color only a small portion of a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table. I need to color only a small portion of the table cell. Like, a small triangle on the right top of the cell. I tried some css and all. But nothing seems to accomplish the same. I prefer css. Don't require css3.

Sample image

[image: A sample image is shown below]

Comment: You could have at least setup a test environment for us... E.g. a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: if you dont want in css3, create one image like triangle and assign it for the background of table cell. keep the background position top right.

Comment: use `background-image` if you want to this by css2.1 otherwise you can accomplish this by css3 shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the shape you want as a small jpg and use this css

```
background-image: url('[image url]');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
```

if you need to alter the size of the background image, you can add `background-size: [size];`

Answer (score 9):

A pseudo element should do the trick.

**EDIT: The `content` of this pseudo-element has no size of it's own but you can color the borders individually and since borders meet at an angle you can make triangles ((search for CSS triangle on SO)**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/jDwCq/56/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> first </td>
        <td> second </td>
        <td> third </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {
    position: relative; /* Needed for pseudo elem */
    height:30px;
}
table td:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:10px solid red;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    z-index:1
}
```

Comment: That does the work. But i'm not sure how it's doing it. Are you coloring the 'content' ?

Comment: @smashIT Not exactly. The `content` has no size of it's own but you can color the borders individually and since borders meet at an angle you can make triangles ((search for CSS triangle on SO)

Comment: Its not that clever, its just a standard way to solve it. +1 from me as this is how I would do it. You should explain to the OP how and what you are doing as they don't seem to understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make that red color as the image(any size that u required).
2. In Html

   `<span style="position:relative;border:1px solid black;width:200px:height:50px">
   <img src="/red color image link" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0">
   <span>`

I have written inline css

Make the container as the position:relative
Red Image as positon:absolute; then top:0 and right:0. 
by using top,right,left,bottom value we can position that image any where